# AS3 objects (buttons) from library not accessible from within certain functions

Tags: actionscript-3, object, reference, null

I'm working on a simple image processor in AS3 and as usual I almost had it finished when an annoying little problem appeared. I want to open an image using a dialog box, and once the image is open I want the "selectBtn" (which is in my Library) to disappear. However when I try the code below I get a:  "Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference". I'm sure it's something simple but I just can't figure it out!

```
// declare variables
var image:Bitmap;
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
var fileRef:FileReference= new FileReference();

selectBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, openImage);

function openImage(event:MouseEvent):void {
fileRef.browse([new FileFilter("Images", "*.jpg;*.gif;*.png")]);
fileRef.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, onFileSelected);
}

function onFileSelected(e:Event):void {
fileRef.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onFileLoaded);
fileRef.load();
}

function onFileLoaded(e:Event):void {
loader.loadBytes(e.target.data);
image = Bitmap(loader.content);
selectBtn.visible = false;
}
```

Comment: If you are using the timeline and key frames, make sure your button exists in all frames where ever this code is called. Also, make sure you gave your button an instance name of "selectBtn"

Answer (score 0):

What Todd says is accurate: where is "selectBtn" defined? Is it on a stage, or nested within some movieclip instance?

Assuming the button exists on the stage, and the code runs in the same frame as the button exists, you could try `this.stage.selectBtn.visible = false;`

Otherwise, trace that you have selectBtn as a reference. Or you could declare a variable to reference it. i.e.:

```
var selectBtnRef:Button = this.stage.selectBtn;
```